# T-SQL - Create a trigger to update the updated record's average time with the average of similar records over the past 90 days?

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers, sql-update

I am trying to create a trigger that when called, will update the most recently updated record's RollingAvgTime column with the average over the past 90 days.

System Information:
SQL Server

Table           :

- BatchLog

Relevant Columns:

- ElapsedTime (Calculated value, the one being averaged)
- RollingAvgTime -Needs a trigger
- Rolling StdDev -Needs a trigger
- DifferenceFromAvg -Needs a trigger

In essence, I am trying to update the last three columns (previously null) to have the relevant information when the record is updated by a stored procedure.

I'm more than happy to provide any more details! Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Here is the code I am using now, it does compile,, but is not correct.

```
CREATE TRIGGER TR_BatchLog_Update
ON dbo.BatchLog
AFTER UPDATE AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @BatchLogNId INT
SELECT
  @BatchLogNId = INSERTED.BatchLogNId
FROM
  INSERTED
INNER JOIN
  DELETED
    ON INSERTED.BatchLogNId = DELETED.BatchLogNId
    -- It's an update if the record is in BOTH inserted AND deleted

UPDATE BatchLog
SET RollingAvgTime = (
 SELECT AVG(ElapsedTime)
 FROM BatchLog
 WHERE BatchLogNId = @BatchLogNId
 AND EndTime <= DATEADD(MONTH, -3, GETDATE())
)
END
GO
```

FINAL:

Working code!

```
Use LogilityPHAdmin
GO
DROP TRIGGER TR_BatchLog_Update
GO
CREATE TRIGGER TR_BatchLog_Update
ON dbo.BatchLog
AFTER UPDATE AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

UPDATE b
SET RollingAvgTime = (
 SELECT AVG(ElapsedTime)
 FROM BatchLog b2
 WHERE b2.EndTime > DATEADD(MONTH, -3, GETDATE())
 AND b2.DivCd = b.DivCd
 AND b2.ProgramName = b.ProgramName
 AND b2.Successful = 1
)
FROM BatchLog b
INNER JOIN inserted I
  ON b.BatchLogNId=i.BatchLogNId


UPDATE b
SET RollingStdDev = (
 SELECT STDEV(ElapsedTime)
 FROM BatchLog b2
 WHERE b2.EndTime > DATEADD(MONTH, -3, GETDATE())
 AND b2.DivCd = b.DivCd
 AND b2.ProgramName = b.ProgramName
 AND b2.Successful = 1
)
FROM BatchLog b
INNER JOIN inserted I
  ON b.BatchLogNId=i.BatchLogNId


UPDATE b
 SET DifferenceFromAvg = (b.RollingAvgTime - b.ElapsedTime)
 FROM BatchLog b
 INNER JOIN inserted I
 ON b.BatchLogNId=i.BatchLogNId

END
GO
```

Comment: And what part of it don't you know how to do?   What is your question?

Comment: @TabAlleman The issue I am having is with the general flow of the trigger. I get that I need to UPDATE BatchLog, and SET RollingAvgTime = something, I'm not sure what that something is. Do I need to calculate the rolling averages and store them in variables then set it equal to that? Thanks for your comment!

Comment: No, don't use variables.  Make the calculation part of your UPDATE statement.  Write a User-Defined Function if you have to.   Google "CALCULATE MOVING AVERAGE IN SQL" for examples.

Comment: @TabAlleman Googling now! Thank you!

Comment: @TabAlleman Do I say something like SET RollingAvgTime = (SELECT ...)? Just not sure where the average is coming from. Sorry for the novice questions.

Comment: Yes, something like that should work.

Comment: For some reason this is not working, editing now.

Comment: Post your code, and maybe we can figure out what's wrong.

Comment: **Word of caution:** a **trigger** on a SQL Server table should be *very nimble and fast* since it's being executed outside of your control, and within the context of the SQL statement that causes it to fire. You should **NOT** put heavy processing and extensive calculations and stuff like that into a **trigger** - that's not a good idea, performance-wise.

Comment: Thank you @marc_s! I do not anticipate this table being any bigger than a few thousand records, maximum. I will take that into account though!

Comment: Your trigger has **MAJOR** flaw in that you seem to assume it'll be called **once per row** - that is **not** the case. The trigger will fire **once per statement**, so if your `INSERT` statements affects 25 rows, you'll get the trigger fired **once**, but then `Inserted` pseudo table will contain 25 rows. Which of those 25 rows will your code select here?? `SELECT @BatchLogNId = INSERTED.BatchLogNId` - it's non-deterministic. You need to rewrite your trigger to take this into account!

Comment: Shoot I see that now. I am having trouble grabbing the correct record (correct being the one that was most recently updated by a stored procedure named Proc_BatchLogUpdate).

Comment: You can't return two columns in your sub-select.   I think you should take out "BatchLogNId" and just return AVG(ElapsedTime).

Comment: @TabAlleman the reason I had that there was to verify that I was updating the correct record. I removed it, but am still not sure how to verify that I have the correct record. NOTE: It compiles now, but is non-deterministic still.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.  Notice how the UPDATE joins to the inserted table so that it will handle multiple inserts, instead of using variables.

```
CREATE TRIGGER TR_BatchLog_Update
ON dbo.BatchLog
AFTER UPDATE AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

UPDATE b
SET RollingAvgTime = (
 SELECT AVG(DATEDIFF(minute,0,ElapsedTime))
 FROM BatchLog b2
 WHERE b2.BatchLogNId = b.BatchLogNId
 AND b2.EndTime <= DATEADD(MONTH, -3, GETDATE())
)
FROM BatchLog b
INNER JOIN inserted I
  ON b.BatchLogNId=i.BatchLogNId

END
GO
```

Comment: This works, and is updating the correct record only! The only issue I have is that the value in the RollingAvgTime column now says '1900-01-01 00:00:00.000' when it should really be an average of 16. The datatype on the column is datetime, is there any way I can get this to display 16?

Comment: 16 what?   days?   seconds?

Comment: Should be minutes. Sorry about the confusion :/

Comment: I truncated the table and now have two records. One took 7 minutes, the other took 0, so I should have a RollingAvgTime on the most recent record of 3.5 minutes, but it still says 1900-01-01 .. .000 The first record now says 1900-01-08, which is the 1900-01-01 + 7 so that's something.

Comment: I'm trying this now
    SELECT AVG(DATEDIFF(minute,BeginTime,EndTime))

Comment: Instead of using the ElapsedTime, which is an INT, I used the actual BeginTime and EndTime which are stored in the table as well.